# Advice needed on collection view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im implementing a collection view based on a project on cocoa controls

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/klsectionselect,

I have 6 items stored in an array.

My question is:   Using an `if` statement, how do I reference items 1 to 6 in the array stored in a the  P list so I can add implementation/action for those items when selected?

So far I tried looking at apple documentation for container view - not really any further forward

I also tried adding if statements with `if ((collectionView = 0))` and other such guesses'

[image]

```
-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.sectionData count];
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[collectionView registerClass:[KLHeaderViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
KLHeaderViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSDictionary* cellDictionary = [self.sectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: [cellDictionary objectForKey:@"image"]]];
[cell.label setText:[cellDictionary objectForKey:@"text"]];
return cell;
}


-(void) didSelectItem:(UICollectionView*)collectionView item:(UICollectionViewCell*) cell {


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note1" message:@"© 2012 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];



}
```

This is what I tried which might help explain

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if 
    ((collectionView = Item 0)){

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note1" message:@"© 2012 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];

    }

else if ((collectionView =Item 1)){

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Note" message:@" © 2012 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];




}

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You can reference the items like you already do in your cellForItemAtIndexPath: method. Are you asking how to access the selected one?

Comment: Apologies if im not explaining this properly. I have six objects yet I only have one implementation (for the alert view) How do I select  item 2, item 3 etc `if` selected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
-(void) didSelectItem:(UICo`enter code here`llectionView*)collectionView item:(UICollectionViewCell*) cell {
```

...you should write:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Answer (score 0):

You implement the delegate method, - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath .

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSDictionary* cellDictionary = [self.sectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Make sure that you have the class set up as the collection view's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain I am understanding your question, but you might try looking at the selected items row.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row = 0){

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note1" 
                                                    message:@"© 2012 " 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" 
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if (indexPath.row = 1){

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Note" 
                                                    message:@"© 2012 " 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" 
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if ...
```

}